# Some error about UnxUtils Sed in 'for' dos command

Tags: batch-file, sed, cmd

The following batch is tested under win 7 x64, with GNU sed version 4.0.7

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"') do (echo %%a)
```

But the error occurs.

If add "call" or remove quote mark of "sed.exe" as the following, the error disappeared.

Remove the quate mark,

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"') do (echo %%a)
```

But it is not suitable for the full path of sed.exe that includes SPACE,

Add "call",

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call "%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"') do (echo %%a)
```

This can be ok.

If test the command directly,

```
"%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"
```

It is ok as well.

So what is the problem of the 1st syntax?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a command like `for /f %a in ('someCommand') do ...`, a new command process is launched as follows (path may change): `c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c someCommand`.

Substituting your actual command, you get:
`"%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"`

If you wade through the CMD help (`help cmd` or `cmd /?`), you will see that CMD will strip the leading and trailing quote if the first and last characters of the command are quotes. This results in:
`%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt`.
You should be able to see why this fails.

This also explains why it works when you add CALL - the command no longer begins with a quote, so no quotes are stripped.

It is possible to run the command without CALL by enclosing the entire command within an extra set of quotes. However, those extra quotes should be escaped so as not to interfere with the quoting during the initial parsing phase:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^""%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "/%pattern%/ s/(^^[^,]*,)([0-9])(,.*)/\1 \3/ p" "file.txt"^"') do (echo %%a)
```

Comment: Thanks. It runs after add one more quotes. But why, for sed.exe, this quotes have to add ^. The other command can be quoted without ^. For example, `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('""%UnxUtils_path%\md5sum.exe" -b "file.txt""') do (echo %%a)`

Comment: Without the extra set of quotes, then certain portions of your command are quoted, thus protecting against poison characters during the initial batch parsing phase. For example, the quoted argument after `-nr` contains carets. As long as that argument is quoted, then it works fine. But when you add the extra set of unescaped quotes, the argument is no longer quoted during the initial parse, so each caret would have to be escaped as `^^`. By escaping the outer enclosing quotes, the correct portions of your command remain quoted.

Comment: Thanks. you are right. I reviewed `cmd /?` according to your mention. I simplified the `sed` command set in `for` command and tested it once more. `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('""%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "s/[0-9]/ / p" "file.txt""') do (echo %%a)` and `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('""%UnxUtils_path%\sed.exe" -nr "s/^([0-9]^)/ / p" "file.txt""') do (echo %%a)` can run as well without error due to no `()` or escaped `()` between quotes.